# How to run Scrapy unit tests in Pycharm

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, pycharm

I am working with Pycharm, trying to run scrapy unit tests - and it fails to run.
The errors are for missing imports, seems like all imports are failing.
e.g.

```
 Import error... "no module named mock"
```

what I did:

1. Get scrapy from github
2. Run pip to install all dependencies from requirements.txt
3. Installed TOX , made sure I can run the tests using TOX.
4. Configured Pycharm to run tests using py.test

I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04, Python 2.7 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to additionally pip install the [tests requirements](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/tests/requirements.txt):

```
pip install -r tests/requirements.txt  # Python 2
pip install -r tests/requirements-py3.txt  # Python 3
```

That would install the `mock` package and solve the `no module named mock` on Python 2 (assuming you are installing into the same environment, you are running tests from).

---

Note that to run the tests, you should use `tox` (which would also install the missing dependencies from `requirements.txt` during a test run setup phase):

```
tox -- tests/test_loader.py
```

(just done all of that and the tests are running and passing for me).

FYI, here is my PyCharm configuration for the tox runner:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, do you mean I should configure Pycharm to use tox?

Comment: @omerschleifer I think you can keep the `pytest` runner to run the tests after you install the dependencies with `pip` (the first part of the answer). By the way, the `py.test` command in this case should look like `py.test --cov=scrapy --cov-report= tests/test_loader.py`. Or, the second option, configure tox to run the tests (in this case, it would install dependencies automatically) - this is probably a better way since it is recommended in the docs.

Comment: thanks agian, still after installing tests requreiments, I can run using tox, same as before - but fail In Pycharm studio. I don't see an option to set tox as the runner in pycharm

Comment: @omerschleifer okay, thanks, I've updated the answer and included a screenshot of my tox runner configuration for scrapy.

Comment: Here's a screencast that shows setting up tox in PyCharm: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmBbR97Vsv8

Comment: thanks , that's been a hugh help, I also had to make sure I have ownership of tox (not as root) to make it work - but now it does